# How to reuse test case in Boost test framework?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

For example I have following test case:

```
#include <MyClass.hpp>
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test )
{
    MyClass o1(42), o2(21);
    BOOST_CHECK( o1.is_valid() );
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( o1 == o2 * 2 );
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL ...
    ...
}
```

There are several similar classes that had implemented same methods, would like to test them by the same logic, test cases might be like following:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test1 )
{
    MyClass1 o1(42), o2(21);
    BOOST_CHECK( o1.is_valid() );
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( o1 == o2 * 2 );
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL ...
    ...
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test2 )
{
    MyClass2 o1(42), o2(21);
    BOOST_CHECK( o1.is_valid() );
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( o1 == o2 * 2 );
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL ...
    ...
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test3 )
{
    MyClass3 o1(42), o2(21);
    BOOST_CHECK( o1.is_valid() );
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( o1 == o2 * 2 );
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL ...
    ...
}

...
```

Is there a way to reuse logic in the test case?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [template test cases](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/test_cases/test_organization_templates.html).

```
#include <MyClass.hpp>    
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>

typedef boost::mpl::list<MyClass1,MyClass2,MyClass3> test_types;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE( my_test, T, test_types )
{
    T o1(42), o2(21);
    BOOST_CHECK( o1.is_valid() );
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( o1 == o2 * 2 );
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL ...
    ...
}
```